# What is the expression $\sqrt{8\cdot32\cdot(-3)^2}$ equal to?

Tags: roots, radicals

What is the expression $\sqrt{8\cdot32\cdot(-3)^2}$ equal to?

Sorry for the basic question. I am a little confused when solving such problems. They are very easy, I know, but still... Which is the easiest algorithm and how would you solve it? We are supposed to use the rule that $$\sqrt{a^2b}=a\sqrt{b},a\ge0, b\ge0,$$ right? What would you do to solve the problem? I was thinking about $$8=4\times2\\32=8\times4\\(-3)^2=3^2$$ but are we supposed to continue this to $$8=4\times2=2\times2\times2=2^3\\32=8\times4=2^3\times2^2=2^5?$$ How can we still use $\sqrt{a^2b}=a\sqrt{b}$ then? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the right idea... $8 = 2^3, 32 = 2^5, 8\cdot 32 = 2^8, (-3)^2 = 3^2...$

$\sqrt {2^8\cdot 3^2} = (2^8\cdot 3^2)^\frac 12 = 2^4\cdot 3 = 48$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why did you write the square root as $(2^8.3^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ the second time?

Comment: It is a different notation with the same meaning.  I think that it is a more useful notation.  It allows us to use the algebra we have already learned for integer powers.

Comment: So here we are basically multiplying $8\times\frac{1}{2}$ and $2\times\frac{1}{2}$ to get $4$ and $1$, right? $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: That is really cool. Can I always use it when working with square roots?

Comment: If you had  $\sqrt {2^3}$ you could say $\sqrt {2^3} = (2^3)^\frac 12 = 2^\frac 32$ and be entirely correct, but your teacher will probably want you to say $2\sqrt 2.$  Once you have shown that you know what you are doing, teachers will let you leave it however is most convenient for the problem at hand.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't get why $2\left(2^\frac{1}{2}\right)=2^\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: $(2^a)(2^b) = 2^{a+b}.$ If $a = 1,$ and $b = \frac 12$ then $(2^{1})(2^\frac 12) = 2^{1+\frac 12} = 2^{\frac 32}$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Maybe in cases like this it is easier to use the rule I have written in my post.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{8\cdot32\cdot(-3)^2} = \sqrt{8\cdot32\cdot9} = 3 \cdot \sqrt{8\cdot32} = 3 \cdot \sqrt{16\cdot16} = 3 \cdot 16 = 48$

Answer (score 1):

Since $(-3)^2=3^2$, the expression simplifies to
$$
\sqrt{8 \cdot 32 \cdot3^2} \, ,
$$
meaning that you can set $a=3$ and $b=8\cdot32=256$.